# Need to make column names bold in excel spreedsheet while exporting frm mysql table in php

Tags: php, mysql, xls

I need to make column names bold in excel spreedsheet while exporting frm mysql table in php. Please check the the code given below:

```
<?php

  include '../Scripts/connect.php';    

$sql = "Select u.firstname, u.lastname, q.module, q.title, q.description, a.option, a.correctAnswer, a.userAnswer, a.isCorrect FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 u on u.userID = a.user INNER JOIN table3 q on q.questionPageID = a.questionPageID";

    $result = @mysql_query($sql)    or die("Couldn't execute query:
".mysql_error().'
'.mysql_errno());

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');   //define header info for browser
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$dbTable.'Answers'.date('Ymd').'.xls');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');

    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++)   // show column names as names of MySQL fields
        echo mysql_field_name($result, $i)."\t";
    print("\n");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        //set_time_limit(60); // you can enable this if you have lot of data
        $output = '';
        for($j=0; $j < mysql_num_fields($result); $j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $output .= "NULL\t";
            else
                $output .= "$row[$j]\t";
        }
        $output = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", ' ', $output);
        print(trim($output))."\t\n";
    }
?>
```

Right now its just exporting data in normal format.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you need to create an actual Excel BIFF (.xls) or OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) file using one of the many libraries for PHP written for just that purpose (such as [PHPExcel](http://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)) rather than a tab-separated value file

Comment: I know this library but I need quick hack job for this. Columns I need to make bold are: firstname, lastname, module, title, description, option, correctAnswer, userAnswer, isCorrect